# Correlation and probability among categorical data of a dataframe - metrics (suggestions)

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, probability, correlation

I have a dataset to study but I am not sure how to approach it and I would really appreciate some guidance here. I am in need of keywords and metrics that I should calculate and methods to apply. Any links to read online examples are more than welcome!!!

The dataset is formed upon the following concept:
There are 100 fish in a tank and I study every and each one of them for 2 health problems (cause A and cause B). The causes may become apparent with symptoms that appear on certain parts of the body of the fish: stomach, eyes, skin.

Consequently, the dataset will have the following format:

```
Fish_ID   body_part   cause
      1         eye       A
      1     stomach       B
      1        skin       A
      2         eye     Nan
      2     stomach       B
      2        skin       A
      3         eye       B
      3     stomach       A
      3        skin       A
    100         eye     Nan
    100     stomach     Nan
    100        skin       A
```

I would like to see whether there is a pattern or a correlation between the symptoms. I give an example below.

- cause A, eye problems come frequently with skin problems, but stomach problems are more independent.
- cause B, symptoms on different body parts are independent.

The idea is to study whether two or more body parts may likely experience symptoms of the same cause or, in other words, whether a problem (the problem could be a virus or an environmental factor – it does not really matter) may target more or less equally different body parts.

Thank you in advance for all your ideas and suggestions, highly appreciated and I apologise if this is not a very good question.

Comment: Interesting question , but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. My advice is to make this is as simple as possible; I'm thinking just tabulating the symptoms conditional on the causes is enough. I.e. for each cause, make a table of the symptoms.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I am trying to work on it by classifying the causes (3 classes: A, B and NaN converted into numbers 1, -1 and 0 respectively). Then, I will unstack the body_part column to make it columns and the values in these columns should be the classes. I am thinking to ```df.corr()``` the final frame to see the pairs that are highly correlated. Maybe, later, I will make an account at stats and post it there as well with this approach I just described.

Comment: Ordinary correlation doesn't make any sense here. For one thing there is no unique way to encode the categories as numbers. Every different encoding will yield a different result, and there is no reason to prefer one or another. Mutual information makes sense for categorical data, so that's an option, although not all that enlightening; you will compute the MI as being 0.2 or 0.4 bits, then what? When you repost your question, you probably will want to say more about what are the larger goals you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hot encode body_part column as the values are discrete and then you can find the relation by using many machine learning techniques. one of the very basic visualization technique that works in this case is Violin plots in your case by which you can come to a conclusion and you have only 2 discrete value for the column cause so it can also be hot encoded and should be set as a target variable.

[violin plots](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/violin-plot-for-data-analysis/) follow this link for more detailed explanation of violin plots

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will start working on violin plots first. Can you explain the term "hot encode", please?

Comment: when the data contains numbers or continuous elements like [0, 0.5, 1, 1.2, 2.3......] they are called continuous kind of data. But when the data is discrete like result of blood test data is limited to some outputs only either positive or negative so in that case we hot encode the values but making assumption that positive => 1 and negative =>0 to make the data mathematically compatible you must find more detailed explanations on internet. Do accept the solution if found helpfll.